# How to stop an audio if we need to play another audio

Tags: jquery, audio

I have written code to play two audio if we click on the respective link.How to write jquery to stop the first audio if we click on second link while first one is playing and vice versa.

```
<p>Audio1</p>
    <audio id="playauido1">
        <source src="audio1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('playauido1').play()"> Paly first audio </a>
<p>Audio2</p>               
    <audio id="playauido2">
        <source src="audio2.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('playauido2').play()"> Paly second audio </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

audioElement has a `paused` property.so if you wanna check whether other audio files is playing or not, you can do something like

```
<script>
 function stopPlaying(audioElement) {
   if(!audioElement.paused){
     audioElement.pause();
   }
 }
</script>
<p>Audio1</p>
    <audio id="playauido1">
        <source src="audio1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('playauido1').play();stopPlaying(document.getElementById('playauido2'));"> Paly first audio </a>
<p>Audio2</p>               
    <audio id="playauido2">
        <source src="audio2.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('playauido2').play();stopPlaying(document.getElementById('playauido1'));"> Paly second audio </a>
```

if you have more audio files, you could make an array to store audio elements and do for-loop in `stopPlaying` function to check and pause audio files.

But Actually if the audio's already pausing when you call .pause(),it will do nothing so you don't have to check if it's playing or not. just call pause()

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('playauido1').play();playauido2.pause();">
```

this is simpler and easier